# Won't saved some submission to the file directory

Tags: php, file, validation, directory

Any further submission after the first one won't save and create new line in the directory

Any help or teaching would be greatly appreciate it!

Below is the form code, and the one after is the php code

```
<body>

<?php
      if (!isset ($_POST["date"])){
        $date = date("d/m/y");
        }else{
        $date = $_POST["date"];
        }
?>

    <div id="formWrapper">
        <form action="jobsprocess.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset class="first">
            <h1>Job Vacancy System</h1>
            <label class="labelOne" for="positionid">Position ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="positionid" id="positionid" />

            <br />

            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />

            <br />

            <label for="description">Description:</label>
            <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea>

            <br />

            <label for="date">Closing Date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo $date?>" />

            <br />

            <label for="position">Position:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="position" value="full time">Full Time
            <input type="radio" name="position" value="part time">Part Time

            <br />

            <label for="contract">Contract</label>
            <input type="radio" name="contract" value="on-going">On-going
            <input type="radio" name="contract" value="fixed term">Fixed Term

            <br />

            <label for="applicationby">Application by:</label>
            <label for="post">Post</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="applicationby[]" id="post" value="Post" />
            <label for="mail">Mail</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="applicationby[]" id="mail" value="Mail" />

            <br />

            <label for="location">Location:</label>
            <select name="location" form="locationform">
            <option value="---">---</option>
            <option value="act">ACT</option>
            <option value="nsw">NSW</option>
            <option value="nt">NT</option>
            <option value="qld">QLD</option>
            <option value="sa">SA</option>
            <option value="tas">TAS</option>
            <option value="vic">VIC</option>
            <option value="wa">WA</option>
            </select>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
            <input class="btn" name="post" type="submit" value="Post">
            <input class="btn" name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
            <a class="home" href="index.php">Return to Homepage</a>
            </fieldset>

        </form>

</body>
```

The one below is the php code

```
<?php
//Opening, and creating a path for diretories to create
$newdir = "../../data/jobs2";
umask(0007);

$errors = array(); //sets an error array, this will append to an error string
$applicationArray = (isset($_POST['applicationby']) ? $_POST['applicationby'] : null); 


if (isset($_POST["positionid"])) 
{
    $positionID = $_POST["positionid"];         
    $patternID = "/^P[0-9]{4}$/";                       //This regex ensure that the first letter is start with P following number 0-9 in length of 4.                                                  
    if (preg_match($patternID, $positionID))        //check if the statuscode is matches with the regex
    {
        $ans = "";
        $length = strlen($positionID);
        echo $positionID . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "Please fill in Position ID as they are mandatory field");       //To ensure and detect if there is any error
}

if (isset ($_POST["title"])) 
{
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z\s\.,!]{0, 20}*$/";         //This regex ensure that alphanumeric character, space, comma, period, and exclamation mark, other symbols or characters are not allowed and maximum of 20 alphanumeric characters.
    if (preg_match($pattern, $title))        //Check that the status if matches with the regex
    {
        echo $title . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Please fill in Status as they are mandatory field!");
}

if (isset ($_POST["description"])) 
{
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $patternDescription = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._ \t]{1,260}$";       //This regex ensure that the description is set to maximum character is up to 260
    if (preg_match('/' . $patternDescription . '/', $description))       //Check that the description is matches with the regex
    {
            echo $description . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Please fill in Description as they are mandatory field!");
}

if (isset ($_POST["position"]))         
{
    $positionButton = $_POST["position"];
    echo $positionButton . "<br />";
}
else
{
    //Not possible unless in exceptional circumstances
    array_push($errors, "Please choose the position");
}

if (isset ($_POST["contract"]))         
{
    $contractButton = $_POST["contract"];
    echo $contractButton . "<br />";
}
else
{
    //Not possible unless in exceptional circumstances
    array_push($errors, "Please choose the contract");
}

if (isset ($_POST["location"]))
{
    $location = $_POST["location"];
    echo $location . "<br />";
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "please choose the location");
}

if (isset($_POST["date"]))          
{
    // writing the date format
    $date = date("d/m/y");          
    echo $date . "<br />";
} else {
    //$date = $_POST["date"];
} 

if (isset($applicationArray)) 
{
    //Display no "array" name, by creating a new variable name
    foreach($applicationArray as $application){
        echo $application . "<br />";
    }
}
//check if file exist
if(!file_exists($newdir)){
//create a directory
    mkdir($newdir, 02770);

$jobTxt = fopen($newdir. "/jobs2.txt", "a");
// This is to ensure that the file is
if  (is_writeable($newdir. "/jobs2.txt")) {
    //write the following variable
    if (fwrite($jobTxt, $positionID . " " . $title . " " . $description . " " . $positionButton . " " . $contractButton . " " . $location . " " . $date . " " . $applicationby . "\n"))
{
}
    echo "<p>Your form has succesfully been submit!</p>";
}
fclose($jobTxt);
}


if(isset($positionID, $title))
{
//Validation Check

    //Check if characters length is less or more than 5 characters
    if (0 === strlen($positionID > 5 || $positionID < 5)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Your characters length is either less or more than 5 characters<br/>");
    }



        //Check if characters length is less or more than 20 characters
    if (0 === strlen($title > 20)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Your characters length is more than 20 characters, the maximum number is 20 alphanumeric characters!<br/>");
    }



    //Check if Position ID is left not blank
    if (0 === preg_match("/\S+/", $positionID)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> You forgot to fill in the Position ID!<br />");
    }



    //Check if Title is left not blank
    if (0 === preg_match("/\S+/", $title)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> You forgot to fill in the Title! <br />");
    }


    //Check if user made a mistake with typo
    if (0 === preg_match($patternID, $positionID)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> please make sure that the first letter in Status Code is uppercase 'S' following by 4 numbers. <br />");
    }



    //Remind user to avoid the unnecessary symbol
    if (0 === preg_match($pattern, $title)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Please make sure to avoid symbols other than \",.?!\" <br />");
    }
}


if (isset($errors)) 
{
    //Display no array name by changing the variable
    foreach ($errors as $error) 
    {
        echo '<strong>', $error, '</strong>';
    }
}
//provide back to form page link
echo '<a href="jobpostform.php">Back to Form page.</a> <br />';
//provide back to home page link
echo '<a href="index.php">Back to Home page.</a>'; 



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an end bracket to the check if file exist:

```
if (!file_exists($newdir)) {
    mkdir($newdir, 02770);
} // <-- Missing closing bracket.

$jobTxt = fopen($newdir . "/jobs2.txt", "a");
if (is_writeable($newdir . "/jobs2.txt")) {
    if (fwrite($jobTxt, $positionID . " " . $title . " " . $description . " " . $positionButton . " " . $contractButton . " " . $location . " " . $date . " " . $applicationby . "\n")) {
        // I also believe that you want this in the if statement, not outside
        echo "<p>Your form has succesfully been submit!</p>";
    }

}
fclose($jobTxt);
```

Right now you only do everything if the directory does NOT exist.

Comment: Hi immulatin, I see, that is why it won't saved new submission to the file.

Comment: Sure glad it worked for you, please accept this answer for future references.